# db.ExecContext returns an error and the result which also returns an error. Does it make sense to check error twice for the same operation?

Tags: database, go, error-handling

this is a sample of code:

```
r, err := s.GetDB().ExecContext(ctx, query)
if err != nil {
  return err
}
count, err := r.RowsAffected()
if err != nil { // is not it double check?
   return err
}
```

My opinion is that if there was an error it will be reported after Exec, why one need to check it for the second time?

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps this line from documentation explains why one needs to check an error after RowsAffected():
*Not every database or database driver may support this*